# CM12 installation interrupted

Tags: cyanogenmod

Just started installation of cm12 via tool from http://www.cyanogenmod.org/ on my **Nexus 4**
At some point during installation ive got message that it lost connection to the device and i need to reboot or switch usb port.

I rebooted and only thing that i can get now is bootloader. If i go with normal load or recovery it the same screen with "standing cynagenmod guy". And device is doing nothing.

Im running Windows 8 and in fastboot its not detected.

I have tried both adb and fastboot but it seems that they do not see the device.

Is it the end of my phone? Thanks.

Comment: Windows 8 has some problems with adb and fastboot. You can install adb properly with this program: http://dottech.org/21534/how-to-install-adb-and-fastboot-on-your-windows-computer-for-use-with-your-android-phone/ Just select "Y" on every option. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall any existing drivers through device manager/USBDeview and install raw google drivers (you can use [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) for that). On side note, also try this-> http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979 I too have nexus 4 and I too faced drivers problem in windows 8.1, but this was what fixed it for me.

> Is it the end of my phone?

No android devices arent that easy to completely mess up (especially modern ones). So in case you fail to get phone to be detected via fastboot in windows 8, try that in linux (like ubuntu) instead. Thats because there you only need to add USB rules while setting up adb. And until today, I havent faced a single situation personally where it didnt detect my phone.

**Now what to do after your fastboot has been detected?**

First, download twrp or similar recovery. If its in zip form, extract it and get the recovery.img file. If its already in img format, leave it as is. Then open terminal in linux/cmd in windows and use command->

```
fastboot erase recovery
fastboot flash recovery PathToRecoveryAndFileName.img
```

This will flash recovery into your phone. Just download flashable zip on CM rom (do not use any tools this time, get directly flashable zip).

Use `fastboot reboot recovery` to boot it into recovery, push the zip file you downloaded as rom by->

```
adb push PathToROMZIPAndFileName.zip /sdcard/
```

This will push rom zip into sdcard, then simply flash using recovery.

In case you fail to flash recovery from some reason, you can also directly boot into recovery without flashing it right from pc. For this, use command `fastboot boot PathToRecoveryAndFileName.img`

One last thing, in case you decide to use nexus root tookit, it has an in built option to try recovering from bootloop. Select `I cant use recovery` or any such option in that, it should automatically do some work for you.

Comment: Is the fastboot erase instruction necessary to perform? I usually don't do that while flashing any partition and didn't face any issue yet. Perhaps, I'm lucky in this case. :) Can this instruction not be skipped?

Comment: Actually yes, since there can be only one recovery in system so its always over-written and there are no side effects really if erase command is skipped. Whenever I create scripts for personal use I erase out systems and stuff too, so its kinda becoming habit to write erase command along everywhere. Otherwise there's no problem if this command is skipped ;)

Comment: I have managed to install twrp but adb does not detecting device

Comment: Two things: 1) Uninstall any existing drivers of ANY phone (whether nexus or not) through USBDeview/device manager. Then try reinstalling raw drivers from nexus root toolkit (if the drivers provided in that adb installer didnt work, else try those first). Whatever the case, its driver issue. So you know what to do... 2) Making windows (especially 8.1) detect phone in fastboot has always been a problem. If you can, use a linux distro like ubuntu. It has much more higher success rate. You can refer [here](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb)

Comment: In the end i have used Flash Stock + Unroot from Nexus Root Toolkit and all work fine. Thanks!